# how to call a methode in the superview from the subview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I had a view controller which is initialised in appdelegate.I was added that viewcontroller to the navigation controller with addsubview methode,inorder to show it above the navigation bar.Now i am adding another viewcontrollers view as the subview of this view.Now when i am pressing a button on the subview i need to perform some methodes in the superview.I tried this way`

```
appdelegate.viewcontroller =(ViewController*)self.view.superview;  

    }
    if(appdelegate.viewcontroller==nil)
    {

        NSLog(@"appdelegate viewcontroller nil"); 

    }
    else
    {

    [appdelegate.viewcontroller setmessage:@""];
     }
```

`But it is giving me error like

> [UIView setmessage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.Can anybody point me in where i am going wrong?

Comment: This link is not exactly related to your que . But it may be helpful ---**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302346/how-to-update-superview-from-its-subview-in-ipad?rq=1**

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView* next = [self.view superview]; next; next = next.superview) 
    {
        UIResponder* nextResponder = [next nextResponder];
        if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
        {
            [(UIViewController*)nextResponder viewWillAppear:YES];
        }
    }
```

Comment: how i will assign this to a viewcontroller object?

Comment: appdelegate.viewcontroller = [self viewController];

Comment: [self superview] giving me a warning as there is no instance methode and gone when i changed to [self.view superview] but the actual error stays..also assigning like this giving me assigning incompatable pointer type assigning to

Comment: u are doing this in the appdelegate? don't do it in appdelegate.. do it in the viewcontroller, you will be calling the superview.

Comment: i am doing it in viewcontroller